# convert html to pdf, all Css is not applied with itextsharp library c#

Tags: c#, html, itext

I am using iTextsharp library to generate a pdf from a html file in my C# code, I am using following code to generate the pdf

```
var elements = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, css);
foreach (var element in elements)
{
     document.Add(element);
}
```

my css contains :first-child and :last-child of  tag, but it's style is not getting applied in the generated pdf file.

Is there any solution available for getting solve this issue ?

Comment: Why don't you go with: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf ?

Comment: @Vishal Suthar, Thank you for suggestion. but I just want to generate pdf from c# code, not to use any 3rd party software for it.

Comment: It's not a software, it's just a wrapper for c# and also an open source.

Answer (score 0):

I would use WkHTMLtoPDF for this. This is an open source utility that uses the QT WebKit rendering engine to render the page to a PDF. I have had very good results with this in the past. You can learn more by visiting http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

There are also a wrappers available for C#. This one hasn't been updated in a while but I have had good results with it in the past. https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin

I hope that helps!

Cheers